# Knockout foreach observableArray seems to not for array of objects

Tags: knockout.js

I am not sure why my foreach sections isn't working? The very first data-bind text: Id is working though.

**Knockout:**

```
import Knockout from 'knockout';

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable();
    self.Sections = ko.observableArray();
};

var viewModel = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$.getJSON("/api/projects/3455", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    viewModel.Id(data.Id);
    viewModel.Sections(data.Sections);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-bind="text: Id">
    <div data-bind="foreach: Sections">
        <div data-bind="text: Id"></div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**Returned JSON:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your html with the first `text` binding because it replaces the whole content of your top level `div` element and you lose your foreach.

So you need to move the text binding inside your top div:

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="text: Id"></div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: Sections">
        <div data-bind="text: Id"></div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Or using the containerless binding syntax if you don't like to have the extra `div`:

```
<div>
    <!-- ko text: Id --><!-- /ko -->
    <div data-bind="foreach: Sections">
        <div data-bind="text: Id"></div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ooh, well-spotted, that's unpredictable view code in the question's post. However, even though I would've also expected the behavior you suggested, it seems that [with](https://jsfiddle.net/1eqcm889/) nor [without](https://jsfiddle.net/aexf4ccb/) a top level `Id` the contents are overwritten. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Jeroen it does not matter what you have in your Id initially. The KO text binding "sets the element’s content to a text node with your parameter value. Any previous content will be overwritten." so the inner elements are lost at the moment when you call `ko.applyBindings`

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, I didn't interpret my own example correctly. My bad!!

Comment: `s/loose/lose/`